# Facebook and Google OAuth work fine when tested using testflight but they don't when the app is been reviewed for publication

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

I've just finished developing an Ionic app and I submitted the app for review, but it got rejected for a bug I cannot reproduce.
It uses Google and Facebook OAuth. Tested in my iPhone both work fine. I also made the app available for testing using Testflight and the three people who I ask for help with this issue could log in successfully using either of those two methods.
The reviewer, however, could not, and my app got rejected twice. They don't have any logs about it and everything is working fine server side.

I thought at fist that it had to do with my server configuration, so I changed everything to support https calls. I also tried to look for some configuration I missed about using both APIs but to no avail. I talked to the reviewer but the answer was the same as before with only the steps to reproduce the problem, which are the same ones that work in every one of my tests.

These are the versions I'm using:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@ionic-native/core": "~4.12.0",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.20.0",
        "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^4.2.1",
        "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "7.0.0",
    }
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
                "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "4.40.0"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
                "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.+"
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very specific but I'm posting it here for everyone with the same issue:

The tester disabled push notifications from his iPad. After login, I would ask the device for credentials for push notifications, but because it was disabled, the error occurred.